# orderBy sorts days right but months false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to order my data with the following ng-repeat option

```
ng-repeat="date in dateList | orderBy:'dateObject':false"
```

Each dateObject contains a new Date object with the corresponding date.

My output is right on the first look:

```
22-03-2017
23-03-2017
24-03-2017
Etc.
```

When I add further dates of the following month to this list I get weird behavior:

```
01-04-2017
02-04-2017
03-04-2017
04-04-2017
22-03-2017
23-03-2017
Etc.
```

I have no clue why the months are sorted different than the days...

Comment: Looks like it's just sorting in alphabetical order.

Comment: `dateObject` is a string representing a date or an actual `Date` instance?

Comment: @sp00m it is a new instantance of the Date object which get its value set by another Date object

Comment: Date objects don't display in DD-MM-YYYY by default; those must be strings.

Comment: @DanielBeck this is a short summary to understand the problem, this is not how its displayed, i display the stringified data. The dateObject is the basic Date object.

Comment: I found my problem... My data was wrong... anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort it in your controller, using a filter to get a format that can be sorted alphabetically.

```
$filter('date')(date.dateObject, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Or use it in a custom sorting function

```
$scope.myValueFunction = function(date) {
   return $filter('date')(date.dateObject, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
};
```

and then use it on your html

```
ng-repeat="date in dateList | orderBy: myValueFunction"
```

Comment: The function was not my problem, but your way also works. So I guess it is the correct answer. My question was wrong.